# How to reset password of salesforce dev account if I don't remember security questions

Tags: forgot-your-password, change-password, salesforce-support

I forgot my password of salesforce dev account and don't remember my security question. Suggested solution for this is to create a support ticket for this and salesforce support ppl will reset my password manually. I tried for that, But you know there is no way to submit support ticket without loging in to salesforce account. 
Is there any support email address I can send a mail for reseting my password ?

Vishnu

Answer (score 1):

For developer support, the tech support team actively monitor the developer forums. This is typically the most expedient way to go about opening a ticket for DE org related problems.

Typically I suggest opening it in the topic that relates to your problem.

If it is just a lock out issue, probably use general development.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=General_Development&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS

If you have problems with which have to do Trailhead, then there is a tag for trailhead, too.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?communityId=09aF00000004HMGIA2#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=Trailhead&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no  way to reset password if you have forgot the security question of your developer account. You have to contact salesforce support for this by raising a ticket to them using any of the production/sandbox org if you have access to any of the org.

If you have salesforce API access/outbound message  (Session ID) of your developer org then you can reset the password by own by consuming SF APIs.

> Note: You should have ORG ID & Username of Dev org for which you want
>   to raise ticket to them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option I can create a ticket without login, I had to create new dev account and than created a ticket. expected behavior should be to allow any guest user to create ticket or provide an email address where any user can contact to Salesforce Support System if they are not able to login or signup.